# value doesn't exists while reading JSON

Tags: java, json

**My JSON**

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "11/6, Dhandapani St, VGP Seethapathy Nagar, Velachery, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600042, India"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Magazine Road, St Thomas Mount, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600016, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.6 km",
                  "value" : 6589
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "21 mins",
                  "value" : 1268
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to get the distance  value from this JSON.

I am getting value till rows but I get exception while I try to convert this JSON object to JSON Array.

**Success till this**

```
JSONArray rows= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");
JSONObject elements= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
Log.d("Eleemnrs",String.valueOf(elements));
```

**And when I execute below code there is no value for distance**

```
 JSONArray rows= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");
 JSONObject elements= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
 elements.get("distance");
 Log.d("Eleemnrs",String.valueOf(elements));
```

Comment: Is `2019-07-06 17:28:59.523 10648-10648/com.example.newjourney I/System.out:..` also part of JSON? If not please remove. If you are asking about one problem it is good to not introduce others to let others focus only on thing you asked about.

Comment: `elements.get("distance");` gets the object (because that is an object, not a number), and then discards it. You may want to store it in a variable. And then you can get `text` or `value` from it, and that is what you could log easily (a string and/or a number respectively)

Comment: Which value are you looking to get from the distance object? "text" or "value"?

Answer (score 1):

> JSONObject elements= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
>   This result elements is:

```
   {
         "elements" : [
               {
                "distance" : {
                   "text" : "10.3 km",
                 "value" : 10320
               },
                "duration" : {
                   "text" : "20 mins",
                   "value" : 1178
               },
                "status" : "OK"
              }
        ]
   }
```

If you should get the `distance` value you should `get("elements")` first and then getJsonObject(0).get("distance")

Comment: But i dont know how to get the element

Comment: @subash chandru It's a nested construct.`JSONObject rows0= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);`And then `JSONArray elements = (JSONArray)rowsObj.get("elements")`.And then `JSONObject element0 = (JSONObject)elements.get(0)`.And  then `JSONObject distance =(JSONObject) element0.get("distance")`.You should learn more about the construct of building json.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making use of the object when you did elements.get("distance")

```
JSONArray rows= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");
JSONObject elements= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
//Here you are not assigning the distance object to any variable. It is simply discarded
elements.get("distance"); 
Log.d("Eleemnts",String.valueOf(elements));
```

You can modify your code as follows to get the distance object into a JsonObject and read the values you require from it.

```
JSONArray rows= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");
JSONObject elements= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
JsonObject distance = elements.get("distance"); 
Log.d("Distance text is ", distance.getString("text"));
Log.d("Distance value is ", distance.getInt("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    JSONArray rows= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");
                    JSONObject elements= (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
                    JSONArray one= (JSONArray) elements.get("elements");
                    JSONObject two=(JSONObject)one.get(0);
                    JSONObject three=(JSONObject)two.get("distance");
                    int finalvalue= (int) three.get("value");
```

Carved out the answer!!!